# Objective-C :: How to use NSAutoreleasePool for NSMutableRequest - asynchronous request?

Tags: objective-c, nsautoreleasepool

In a view controller I am doing a lot of NSMutableRequest calls asynchronously. In call back method I am handling the response. These all requests are autoreleased. Here, I want to know how to use NSAutoReleasePool to release these autoreleased objects. Can you please clarify on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Autoreleased object means that it's being released for you (`auto` standing for `self` in latin (I think)). The release of these objects is being managed by `NSAutoreleasePool` in `main.m` file's `main` function. You don't need to do anything if you're not `retain`ing or `copy`ing them explicitly.